# how to install scikit-image 0.14 version?

Tags: python

I need to install scikit-image 0.14 version to use seam_carving() which was removed after 0.15.

I tried few times and I never have luck.

Here is what I did, I also tried 0.14.5 or 0.14.2. Thanks for your help

```
pip install scikit-image==0.14.3
```

Collecting scikit-image==0.14.3
Using cached scikit-image-0.14.3.tar.gz (27.3 MB)
from Cython import **version**
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-95akg_73\scikit-image_0c091bf1d2c14ed1bf9f31d575a3364b\setup.py", line 111, in <module>
    setup(
  File "C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\skimage14\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-95akg_73\scikit-image_0c091bf1d2c14ed1bf9f31d575a3364b\setup.py", line 70, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('skimage')
  File "C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\skimage14\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1016, in add_subpackage
    config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
  File "C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\skimage14\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 982, in get_subpackage
    config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
  File "C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\skimage14\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 924, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "skimage\setup.py", line 14, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('feature')
  File "C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\skimage14\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1016, in add_subpackage
    config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
  File "C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\skimage14\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 982, in get_subpackage
    config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
  File "C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\skimage14\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 924, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "skimage\feature\setup.py", line 22, in configuration
    cython(['_haar.pyx'], working_path=base_path)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-95akg_73\scikit-image_0c091bf1d2c14ed1bf9f31d575a3364b\skimage\_build.py", line 41, in cython
    raise RuntimeError('Cython >= %s is required to build scikit-image from git checkout' \
RuntimeError: Cython >= 0.23.4 is required to build scikit-image from git checkout
Cython >= 0.23.4 not found; falling back to pre-built geometry.c
Cython >= 0.23.4 not found; falling back to pre-built transform.c
Cython >= 0.23.4 not found; falling back to pre-built interpolation.c
Cython >= 0.23.4 not found; falling back to pre-built _draw.c
Cython >= 0.23.4 not found; falling back to pre-built corner_cy.c
Cython >= 0.23.4 not found; falling back to pre-built censure_cy.c
Cython >= 0.23.4 not found; falling back to pre-built orb_cy.c
Cython >= 0.23.4 not found; falling back to pre-built brief_cy.c
Cython >= 0.23.4 not found; falling back to pre-built _texture.c
Cython >= 0.23.4 not found; falling back to pre-built _hessian_det_appx.c
Cython >= 0.23.4 not found; falling back to pre-built _hoghistogram.c
----------------------------------------
```

WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/ae/7988e65bb8accb894ffb3ed97ff572f9f85eacc737c03cd954b89809ca49/scikit-image-0.14.3.tar.gz#sha256=f05eab2df885fb6fde3df0e4d24c9c620d6474ea0eb949fd45f6f634925dd514 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-image/) (requires-python:>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikit-image==0.14.3 (from versions: 0.7.2, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.3, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.2, 0.11.3, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.14.2, 0.14.3, 0.14.5, 0.15.0, 0.16.2, 0.17.1, 0.17.2, 0.18.0rc0, 0.18.0rc1, 0.18.0rc2, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.18.2rc1, 0.18.2rc2, 0.18.2, 0.18.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for scikit-image==0.14.3

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved it by installing Cython:

```
pip install cython
```

After that, the pip install scikit-image command did not show any more errors.